# Javascript generate 5 random numbers whose sum is equal to 100

Tags: javascript

I saw several solutions in python and java here but I didn't find anything using javascript. How do I generate 5 random numbers whose sum is equal to 100?

// output: {10, 20, 50, 10, 10}

Comment: Can those solutions not be converted?

Comment: Positive integers only? Or can it include 0 and decimals?

Comment: You could generate 4 random numbers and then subtract them from 100 to get a fifth number, but it won't be a random fifth number, it will be a very specific fifth number.

Comment: @James well technically every "random" number that is generated by a computed is only pseudorandom, it is not only about the fifth one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let sum = 100
const numbers = []
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * sum)
    sum -= randomNumber < 0 ? 0 : randomNumber
    numbers.push(randomNumber < 0 ? 0 : randomNumber)
}
numbers.push(sum)
console.log(numbers, numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) // 5 random numbers of sum 100
```